# Django Rest Framework class-level variables

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've started using DRF recently and noticed that it asks us to use class-level variables, like `authentication_classes` below, to set auth, permissions, rendering, etc.

```
class ListUsers(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)

    def get(self, request):
        pass
```

My first question is what are these variables called?  Is "class-level" the right term?  And secondly, how do these work?  This kind of usage is strange to me -- declaring "special" variables, but not using them yourself in the class' subsequent statements.

Comment: Why is that strange? They're used in some of the methods that APIView provides, or by other classes that interface with APIView.

Comment: I guess I expected to set `self.authentication_classes` or to call a method.  The style initially left me wondering if things would break if I didn't declare some of these variables, and I'm still not sure what all the possible declarations are.

Comment: You can't do either of those things in the class declaration itself, because the instance doesn't exist yet. The [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-attributes) lists the attributes that can be set.

Comment: Ah, my confusion was just due to not understanding python well enough.  Those are indeed class-level vars and they stick around for use by the instance.

Comment: It will help to understand that even class in Python is an object so you can pass that class whenever you want. `APIView` will take care of creating instance of that class and calling it's methods when needed.